# CCRotateTo set CCW or CW

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

The title is pretty explicit. How can i set the direction in which i rotate a CCSprite with CCRotateTo?

i.e. Rotating CCW or CW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CCRotateBy instead of to. Then set positive or negative offsets depending on the direction needed. CCRotateTo takes the closet direction

Answer (score 0):

I think, the only way you can manage it is to set positive or negative offsets from current angle.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sprite.rotation = 0;
//CW
[sprite runAction:[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:2.0 angle:360]];
//CCW
[sprite runAction:[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:2.0 angle:-360]];
```